# PHP Mail Form won't send all Form Fields to Email

Tags: php, email

The `s_name` and `s_email` fields don't show up in the email sent, only the attachments and message show up. Please assist with any changes to the code to show all form fields in the email.

I have looked at a number of posts but can't seem to find the answer to the problem and assistance will be appreciated.

```
<?php
if($_POST && isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $recepient_email    = "recepient@yourmail.com"; //recepient
    $from_email         = "info@your_domain.com"; //from email using site domain.
    $subject            = "Attachment email from your website!"; //email subject line

    $sender_name = filter_var($_POST["s_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    //capture sender name
    $sender_email = filter_var($_POST["s_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender email
    $sender_message = filter_var($_POST["s_message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message
    $attachments = $_FILES['file'];

    //php validation
    if(strlen($sender_name)<4){
        die('Name is too short or empty');
    }
    if (!filter_var($sender_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        die('Invalid email');
    }
    if(strlen($sender_message)<4){
        die('Too short message! Please enter something');
    }

    $file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
    $boundary = md5("sanwebe.com"); 

    if($file_count > 0){ //if attachment exists
        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

        //message text
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($sender_message)); 

        //attachments
        for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++) {
            if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])) {
                if($attachments['error'][$x]>0) { //exit script and output error if we encounter any
                    $mymsg = array(
                        1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini",
                        2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form",
                        3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded",
                        4=>"No file was uploaded",
                        6=>"Missing a temporary folder"
                    ); 
                    die($mymsg[$attachments['error'][$x]]); 
                }

                //get file info
                $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
                $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
                $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];

                //read file 
                $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$x], "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)

                $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
                $body .= $encoded_content; 
            }
        }
    } else { //send plain email otherwise
        $headers = "From:".$from_email."\r\n".
            "Reply-To: ".$sender_email. "\n" .
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $body = $sender_message;
    }

    $sentMail = @mail($recepient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) { //output success or failure messages
        die('Thank you for your email');
    } else {
        die('Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.');  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to isolate or point out the part of the code you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n";
```

You have an extra double quote?  Should be like this:

```
$headers .= "Reply-To:" .$sender_email. "\r\n";
```

Your $sender_name is not used in the email, only when you check if the length is < 4.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see all your form fields doing this?

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Double-check if all your form fields has the `name` attr and if their are matching to fields printed above.